# Can't install mysql-server package

Tags: mysql, package, debian

I am trying to install the mysql-server package on debian and I am getting an error:

```
t@mintserver:~$ sudo apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2.942 kB of archives.
After this operation, 111 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
(Reading database ... 372098 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not installed.
```

I read many other replies that told me to purge the packages, correct dependencies, but nothing works.

```
t@mintserver:~$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2.933 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: did you tried to update the packages list before (apt-update) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, run `sudo dpkg --audit` or `sudo dpkg -C`, it's the same. It probably will suggest to you what to do.

Edit: According to your comment,

> Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ... update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf doesn't exist dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure): installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2 Errors were encountered while processing: mysql-server-5.7

the update-alternatives program failed to find this `mysql.cnf` file.

Could you try creating that file?
Please, do:
`sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf`
filling with this [content](https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/xenial/main/all/mysql-common/5.7.11-0ubuntu6/file/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf):

```
[mysql]
```

Then, try again `dpkg --configure <package>`

Or, this will probably do the job:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-\*
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

If interested, you could also read [A Quick Guide to Using the MySQL APT Repository](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/). They provide different installation approaches for different scenarios.

Comment: `The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
 mysql-server         MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the lates

The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 mysql-server-5.7     MySQL database server binaries and system database setup`

Comment: I tried running the command suggested by dkpg:

`Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7`

Comment: @user101529 I updated my answer suggesting some options. I hope it helps.